# Spring Aspect doesn't work on KafkaListener function when the pointcut is in the interface?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-aop

I've added a pointcut on the GenericMessageListener of spring kafka,
and I am using @KafkaListener, and the aspect doesn't work. (The relationship between GenericMessageListener and @KafkaListener is the Spring creates Listener for user functions with this annotation). If I change the pointcut to the annotation of KafkaListener, it works.

I have two questions:

1. someone says this doesn't work because Spring aspect work on proxy (dynamic proxy or cglib proxy), but I don't quite get why it impacts the pointput on the parent class/interface;
2. how can I change the interface directly so that all classes implement it directly or indirectly can be changed?

The minimum code to reproduce this in a spring kafka project

```kotlin
@Aspect
@Component
class KafkaRedirectionAspect {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    // Kafka OnMessage: cannot work on base class or interfaces with spring aop
//    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.kafka.listener.GenericMessageListener+.*(..))")
    @Pointcut("within(org.springframework.kafka.listener.GenericMessageListener+) && execution(* *(..))")
    fun consumerOnMessagePC(){
    }

    @Around("consumerOnMessagePC()")
    fun consumerRedirectionAdvice(pjp: ProceedingJoinPoint):Any? {
        println("consumer--OnMessageInterface---PointCut works ~~~~")
        return null
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class RedirectionConfig {
    @Bean
    fun createAspect(): KafkaRedirectionAspect {
        return KafkaRedirectionAspect()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(RedirectionConfig::class)
class DemoApplication {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    // redirection topic: "topic-poc-v1-redirection"
    @KafkaListener(id = "consumer-poc", topics = ["topic-poc-v1"])
    fun listen(value: String?) {
        logger.info("Listen with Simple Value, message {}", value)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig(
    @Value("\${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private val servers: String
) {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    @Bean
    fun consumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<String?, Any?> {
        val props: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = servers
        // deserializer with error handling
        props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = ErrorHandlingDeserializer::class.java
        props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = ErrorHandlingDeserializer::class.java
        props[ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        props[ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS] = StringDeserializer::class.java

        return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props)
    }

    // TODO: does the name of bean configuration matter?
    @Bean
    fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Any>? {
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Any>()
        factory.consumerFactory = consumerFactory()
        factory.containerProperties.ackMode = ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD // TODO: this may impact the SDK behavior
        factory.containerProperties.isSyncCommits = true;
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(DefaultErrorHandler(
            null,
            FixedBackOff(
                10,
                1.toLong()
            )))
        return factory
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: For example, where are you using `GenericMessageListener`? Your code does not show it. Instead, I see `@KafkaListener`. Not being a Spring or Kafka user, only knowing about AOP, you cannot expect me or anyone else to know what your code might imply, if there is no reproducer for your problem. You did not even explicitly say what you expect to happen in your code.

Comment: @kriegaex I've added the labels of this question. I think the problem is not about aspectJ but the Spring aspect, and with the context of spring, the question is clear. GenericMessageListener is the interface behind the scene, and the spring-kafka creates it by scanning the KafkaListener Annotation .

Comment: I just trying to answer the question, so allow me to post an answer since can't accept 601+ character here in comment.

Comment: @kriegaex sorry, I haven't got time to read into the original aspectJ and feel it hard for me to translate the under the hook problems into how the aspectJ takes place inside spring aspect.

Comment: I simply asked you to provide a fully self-consistent, reproducible example. If you had followed my links to Stack Overflow FAQs, you would know that. I did not talk about or ask you to read tons of AspectJ documentation, at least not in the first step. I am sure I can answer your question, if you give me a reproducer to inspect. That was the point of my comment. I know enough about Spring AOP to understand a reproducible problem when I see it live. But up to you, if your question is not important enough to provide a reproducer. "Garbage in, garbage out" is also true for questions and answers.

Comment: @kriegaex I really don't understand why would you say so. I really have read the minimal and complete instructions and provided the minimal and complete code lines to reproduce the problem. I don't know what I can do about this. And I am kindly explaining to you this requires a bit context of Spring if you know nothing about Spring, you cannot understand it.

Comment: @kriegaex I have added all code of my test project for you to see if it makes things clearer or worse. But I think this question is clear and simple to reproducable for all who have used Spring, and some has contacted me with some possible answers.

Comment: Someone told me the problem is Spring AOP only works for the instances managed in Spring Context, namely the Spring Beans, and the class that implements the interface (I add advice to) is not maintained as a Bean in the framework. This relies on the knowledge of Spring-Kafka and Spring AOP that's why I told you I changed the problem to Spring-related instead of AspectJ related.

Comment: Thanks for the additional code. What I mean when I said MCVE was a complete project, ideally a Maven or Gradle project on GitHub. I mean something I can just clone and run locally without filling in the gaps, guessing about dependenciey versions etc. The application should also have a main method triggering the method call that you expect to be intercepted by the aspect. The project should not depend on external systems like databases etc. If you need a database, provide a preconfigured in-memory DB or so.

Comment: Regarding Spring AOP: Yes, it only works in connection with Spring-managed beans/components. The Spring documentation explains that, and I have answered or closed as duplicates dozens of questions about that here, because people don't read manuals. But there is always native AspectJ as a more powerful alternative. That might be necessary or not. It might be enough to just add `@Component` to your message 
listener class to be able to intercept its methods. But to answer precisely, I need an MCVE. I do not want to theorise like @KeyboardCorporation had to in his answer.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. the answer is spring-kafka actually has some internal mechanisms that don't create the on-message bean and inject them into context. @kriegaex I am not asking others to explain the Spring manual. Why are you always assuming others' questions as stupid instead of locating the real problem in Kafka-spring mechanisms

Comment: Read again and stop insulting me. I didn't say you are stupid. I gave general advice and asked for a full reproducer several times, so I can analyse your problem instead of speculating and answer more precisely. If I can reproduce the situation, I can help you, otherwise I cannot. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. someone says this doesn't work because Spring aspect work on proxy (dynamic proxy or cglib proxy), but I don't quite get why it impacts the pointput on the parent class/interface;

Ans#1. The reason why your aspect doesn't work when targeting the parent class or interface of `@KafkaListener` is due to how Spring AOP works. Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create a proxy for a given target object. If the target object implements at least one interface, a JDK dynamic proxy is used. If the target object does not implement any interfaces, a CGLIB proxy is created. This means that the proxy can only advise the methods that are part of the interfaces implemented by the target object or its class. If the method you are trying to advise is not part of these interfaces, the advice will not be applied.

> 2. how can I change the interface directly so that all classes implement it directly or indirectly can be changed?

Ans#2. Create a new interface that extends the existing one and add your method to this new interface. Then, have your classes implement this new interface instead of the original one.

This is just a sample execution:

```
public interface NewInterface extends OriginalInterface {
   void newMethod();
}

public class MyClass implements NewInterface {
   @Override
   public void newMethod() {
       // Your implementation here.
   }
}
```

In the above code, `NewInterface` extends `OriginalInterface` and adds a new method `newMethod()`. `MyClass` then implements `NewInterface` and provides an implementation for `newMethod()`. This way, all classes that implement `NewInterface` will have to provide an implementation for `newMethod()`.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem. I am trying to advise all the methods (instead of some code inside the method) of the interface and should be working. And I guess the GenericMessageListener is not managed by Spring so it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is actually that SpringKafkaContainer doesn't create the beans of GenericMessageListener for methods/classes annotated with KafkaListener, and the GenericMessageListener is another way to create consumers different from the KafkaLister annotation.

So the point-cut doesn't align with the internal Kafka way of creating listeners.